# Add condition to where clause eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table `level1 > level2 > level3 > level4` and i have built relationships between tables.
How do I do something like this?

```
level4::with('level3.level2.level1')->whereHas('level3.level2.level1', function($q) use($level2_id){
    return $q->where('level2.id', $level2_id);
})->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to yours pseudo code example:

```
level4::with([
    'level3.level2.level1', function($q) use ($level2_id) {
        return $q->where('level2.id', $level2_id);
    }
])->get();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code, it was quite simple to do what I expected. Fix to

```
level4::with('level3.level2.level1')->whereHas('level3.level2', function($q) use($level2_id){
    return $q->where('id', $level2_id);
})->get();
```

Thank you for helping me.